# How to set visible all methods for non-authenticated users in Django build-in documentation?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

When I open built-in documentation in Django there aren't visible any methods. When I authenticate as a user or admin they become visible. How can I make it available without logging?

**Solution**
I deleted from settings

```
# 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
#     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
# ),
```

and then I created own permissions and added decorators to generic views. Everything is working properly now.

Comment: are you using a login_required() decorator? By default all the views do not require any authentication if not asked for.

Comment: @ShivamSharma No, I don't thinks so. In some generic views I have only added for instance `@permission_classes([GetPermission])` where ```class GetPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method =='GET' or (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser):
            return True
        return False```

Comment: Is that the exact code you copied? Are return True and return False two consecutive statements in the same indent block? or did you miss an else: up there?

Comment: @ShivamSharma I have updated my first post.

Comment: Do you want to make the NOT-Authenticated users see/view a functionality and the Authenticated users to view the functionality as well as edit some data?

Comment: @ShivamSharma I just want the user who has just opened the documentation and is not logged in would be able to see what the user who is logged in and has set `none` as an authentication on left side of the build-in documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151521/discussion-between-shivam-sharma-and-wahtdbogh).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a view that is mapped to a url which is hit whenever Authentication option is set to None(or changed); using javascript; in the left panel.

```
class GetPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            #will only get called for authenticated users.
            if request.GET.get("is_authentication_set_to_null"):
                request.visible = True
            else:
                request.visible = False
        return True
```

Now you can simply use the variable request.visible inside the views or the function of a generic view which has the request object.

In any view:

```
@permission_classes([GetPermission])
def someview(request):
    if request.visible = True:
        #Show those objects that you want to.
        #For example, Update [Path Parameters, Request Body]
    else:
        #Show the restricted/less things you want to show.
        #Show options like: Install the command line client
```

Does this help you?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh check the answer now. I've updated it slightly.

Comment: I have added my changed example generic view to the first post. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything.